# D3.Drag Behavior with nested data

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've had this problem before & it was due to my d3.select not matching up to my attr. However, I do not receive any error from this current bug, I am there somewhat lost in terms of what I have done wrong:

```
 var drag = d3.behavior.drag()
   .origin(Object)
   .on("drag", function(d, i) {
    d.x = d3.event.x;
    d.y = d3.event.y;
  d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate("+nodes[i].locations[0].x+","+nodes[i].locations[0].y+")");

});
```

As you can see I am going through my index to look for all the locations. Would that affect the drag function?

```
   var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
             .data(nodes)

   node.enter().append("g")
        .call(drag)
       .attr('class', 'node');

 node.attr("transform", function(d,i) { return"translate("+nodes[i].locations[0].x+","+nodes[i].locations[0].y+")"; })
```

I am confused why this wont work

I have also attempted to change my ondrag function, however when I try to drag the node it only moves to the centre

```
 .on("drag", function(d, i) {
      nodes[i].locations[0].x = d3.event.x;
      nodes[i].locations[0].y = d3.event.y;
      d3.select(this).attr("transform", "translate ("translate("+nodes[i].locations[0].x+","+nodes[i].locations[0].y+")");
   //    draw();
   });
```

thanks.

Comment: It seems like you're not calling the drag behaviour anywhere. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi @Lars Kotthoff I thought I was calling the drag on my var node - .call(drag). Im simply trying to drag my objects around the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have found a solution to my problem:

```
.on("drag", function(d, i) {
      nodes[i].locations[0].x += d3.event.dx;
      nodes[i].locations[0].y += d3.event.dy;
```